# How to insert to Table that has two foreign keys in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC Project (Forum Project).
I have two tables, one for **Forums** and the other one for **Posts**.
In the Posts table I can make two things: Insert a row for a new post or insert a row for a reply to an exciting Post.

I am using EF Code-First and Linq to Entity, my Forum class:

```
public class Forum{
        public int ForumID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

my Post class:

```
    [Table("Posts")]
   public class Post
    {

       [Column("PostID")]
       public int PostID { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Body { get; set; }

       public int? ReplyCount { get; set; }

       /* Relationship between Classes */
       [ForeignKey("Forum")]
       public int ForumID { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("Posts")]
       public  int ParentPostID { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
       public Forum Forum { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using the Repository pattern .. This is my repository class:

```
  public class ForumRepository : IForumRepository
{
      private SudaneseForumEFDbContext context = new SudaneseForumEFDbContext();

}
```

I need a method in my repository class to save a new post that depends on a ForumId a nd save new Reply to an exciting Post that depends on a ParentPostId.

Sorry my English is not so good.

Comment: The Repository-pattern is unnecessary when using Entity Framework.

Comment: Such a method belongs in a service, not in a repository. A repository has collection semantics, nothing more. That's why Dai asked whether you really need it. Also, without seeing your own first efforts ist's not clear where you're stuck.